ACPI error, hub and usb error when installing Ubuntu 22.04 dual boot
I was installing dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 11 on my laptop. In the first time installation, everything was successful, I spared a 256GB space for Ubuntu, booting from USB driver, then select "install Ubuntu alongside windows", until it prompted that several partitions would be modified, the installation seemed stuck, so I powered off my laptop and restarted it.
After that, I checked the disk, the spared space was partitioned into 2 parts, one primary partition and a EFI system partition. I knew the installation was not successful so I formatted the two partitions and tried to reinstall Ubuntu.
In the second time, when I booted from USB and select "try or install Ubuntu", it cannot enter the installation page normally, and showed:
[0.281699] ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCIO.PB2], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230331/dwsload2-162)
[0.281716] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catelog (20230331/psobject-220)
[1.286604] hub 6-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)
[1.544421] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: unkown chipset (197000a1)
[2.492763] usb 3-2.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32

My hardware specifications:

Legion Pro 5
AMD Ryzen 9 7945HX
NVIDIA RTX 4060
two SSDs

I've tried some solutions, adding nomodeset and acpi=off parameters, but the hub and usb error still exists.
Edit 1:
My laptop has two SSDs, and Windows and Ubuntu were installed on separate SSDs.

As always, when dual-booting with Win8 or newer, disabling its Fast Startup feature is a must. Start with that, update UEFI if available, all of this before trying again. Because you have a current Nvidia you'll need to boot with "safe graphics" option and, during installation, make sure to select the option to install 3rd party drivers, etc. Also understand the UEFI boot process, only one ESP is needed and you have one already and the installer should use it by default even if the system partition is to be created in a different drive.

Furthermore the errors you mentioned can be ignored.

@ChanganAuto Thanks for you comment, I've updated UEFI and tried "safe graphics" option, some errors were gone but still cannot successfully boot. You mentioned to select install 3rd party drivers, however, I cannot even go into the installation page, the errors came out just after I select "try or install Ubuntu" or the boot with safe graphics option. And the most weird thing is that it successfully booted for the first time, but failed after that. And in the first time installation, the installer actually created a ESP on the spared space, rather than using the existing one

The errors still exist after a clean reinstallation of Windows. Actually, there is a loading page with Ubuntu logo after the errors, every time before, the laptop restarted after the loading. However, as I was trying to change boot order by pressing "F12" during the loading page, some booting logs popped up, and Ubuntu install interface showed up after a while. Still don't know what's going on, but finally everything goes on normally.
